# Making X recognize joypad input as activity

Tags: xorg, input-device, joystick

I want my desktop to stop dimming and screen locking when I’m playing my games, but I don’t want to have to disable power saving features before I start playing every time. I feel like other input devices should get as much acknowledgement as a keyboard or mouse.

Apparently most desktop environments use XSyncCounter to determine inactivity, but X only registers activity based on mouse and keyboard input. I’d like to configure X to correctly catch my joypad button presses as activity.

Any ideas about how to accomplish this would be appreciated. To be clear, I’m not asking about controlling X via my joypad.

Comment: There is a discussion about the same issue at https://www.reddit.com/r/linux_gaming/comments/58vjjq/how_do_you_keep_your_screen_saver_from/ . There are several proposed solutions there that could be pulled and written up as an answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, my solution actually was to just set the joypad up as an x input device.

On ubuntu, all I had to do was `apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-joystick` and the xorg.conf.d file was even done for me.

A side-effect is that I can move the cursor around with my gamepad, but I kinda like that and I don’t care as long as the screen stops dimming/locking without me needing to constantly disable/reenable power saving features.